# FactoryGirl built My::Class object doesn't return true on is_a?(My::Class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Code is better than words here

```
e = FactoryGirl.build(:company_employee)
e.class                    # => Company::Employee
e.is_a?(Company::Employee) # => false
```

Is that a bug ? (note that is returns true if I do it with simpleer models like user). Could the bug come from the namespace addition ?

Classes

```
# factories/company_employee.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company_employee, class: Company::Employee do
    ...
  end
end

# models/company/employee.rb
class Company::Employee < Professional
  ...
end
```

Comment: Try specifying class name as string in factory, this may be due to some reload issues

Comment: I tried it in my app, and not seeing what you observed.

Comment: @Vasfed, this seems to have fixed my problem, thanks ! Can you add an answer from your comment that I could accept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying class name as string in factory:

```
factory :company_employee, class: 'Company::Employee' do
```

Due to code reloading your `Company::Employee` and class used in factory can be indeed different classes.